# ShapeFile To GeoDatabase Conversion error

Tags: arcpy

I wrote this python code and when i run it nothing happened and it's success

```
import arcpy

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/ShapeFile'

# Set local variables
inFeatures = ['New_Shapefile.shp']
outLocation = 'C:/ShapeFile/test.gdb'

# Execute TableToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```

Comment: Please **edit** the question to explain what you mean by "nothing happened".

Comment: From a syntax perspective, everything looks fine. That leads me to believe  something is wrong with your shapefile or GDB. Perhaps you have one of the names incorrect?

Comment: the code is working fine but when i publish it as geoProcessing service and submit a job in a rest service it raise and error : the dataset "New_Shapefile.shp" doesn't exist or not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code from this:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```

into this:

```
try:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
    print "success"
except:
    print "error"
```